# Problemas com o Realloc

Tags: c, array, memória

Boa tarde , estou com dificuldade em criar um programa que me vai aumentando o tamanho de uma estrutura designada lista , parecida com um array , sempre que a taxa de ocupação dessa lista tem mais de 80 % preenchida então gostaria de aumentar 2 vezes o tamanho , usando o realloc , meu problema é que não consigo ciar mais que 30 elementos da lista , se no while estiver i < 30 ou outro número superior começa a dar errado(Segmentation fault) gostaria de saber porque, obrigado.

```
#include "buffer.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

Buff init_buff() {
  int i = 0;
  Buff x = malloc(sizeof(struct buff));
  x - > size = 1;
  x - > used = 0;
  x - > lis = malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
  while (i < 10) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) x = load_buffer(x, "par");
    else x = load_buffer(x, "impar");
    i++;
  }
  return x;
}

Buff load_buffer(Buff x, char * l) {
  float taxa_ocupacao = x - > used / x - > size;
  //primeiro caso

  if (taxa_ocupacao > 0.8 || taxa_ocupacao == 0) {
    x - > lis = realloc(x - > lis, x - > size * 2 * (sizeof(struct lista)));
    x - > size *= 2;
  }

  x - > lis[x - > used].phrase = l;
  x - > used++;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde! Poste o código em si ao invés de uma imagem. Assim podemos pegar o código e testar para ajudar melhor :)

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente, o erro que está ocorrendo é falta de memória.

Como a cada iteração do *looping* você aloca o dobro de memória, após 30 iterações o *realloc* vai tentar alocar mais de 2<sup>30</sup> (`> 1.073.741.824`) "`struct lista`"s.

Supondo que *struct lista* tenha apenas 1 ponteiro de 64 bits, dá mais de **8Gb** de memória!

Para verificar se é um erro de falta de memória, teste se o ponteiro retornado pelo *realloc* é válido:

```
...
x->lis = realloc(x->lis, x->size*2*(sizeof (struct lista)));
// AQUI!
if (x->lis == NULL) {
  printf("Sem memória!");
  exit(1);
}
x->size*=2;
...
```

Comment: Era de memória sim , obrigado :)